# How list all opened connections in sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Recently I had an error `sqlalchemy` in my production server.

`sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) connection to server at "myserver.com" (myip), port myport failed: FATAL:  remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication superuser connections`

However this application only has a few users (1 or 2) and it's not possible that the database server is not powerful enough.

My application is 100% tested and I would also like to test the number of opened connections.

**Is there a way to list opened connection in `sqlalchemy`?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default connection pool has methods which report connection states:

- `Pool.status()`: report pool state including open connections
- `Pool.checkedout()`: number of open connections
- `Pool.checkedin()`: number of closed connections in the pool

```
>>> engine = sa.create_engine('postgresql:///test')
>>> engine.pool.status()
'Pool size: 5  Connections in pool: 0 Current Overflow: -5 Current Checked out connections: 0'
>>> conn1 = engine.connect()
>>> conn2 = engine.connect()
>>> engine.pool.status()
'Pool size: 5  Connections in pool: 0 Current Overflow: -3 Current Checked out connections: 2'
>>> engine.pool.checkedin()
0
>>> engine.pool.checkedout()
2
>>> conn1.close()
>>> engine.pool.checkedin()
1
>>> engine.pool.checkedout()
1
>>> conn2.close()
>>> engine.pool.status()
'Pool size: 5  Connections in pool: 2 Current Overflow: -3 Current Checked out connections: 0'
```